# This decoder will only decode classes that adopt NSSecureCoding

Tags: ios, objective-c, watchkit, apple-watch, watchos

From AppDelegate i call this:

```
-(void)application:(UIApplication *)application handleWatchKitExtensionRequest:(NSDictionary *)userInfo reply:(void (^)(NSDictionary *))reply{

    [SavedSearchesHack getAllMatches:^(MatchCollection * _Nonnull matchCollection) {
        reply(@{@"response" : matchCollection});
    }];
}
```

And then i get this error when calling the reply:

*** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInvalidUnarchiveOperationException', reason: 'This decoder will only decode classes that adopt NSSecureCoding. Class 'Test.MatchCollection' does not adopt it.'

```
    public class func openParentApplication(userInfo: [NSObject : AnyObject], 
    reply: (([NSObject : AnyObject], NSError?) -> Void)?) -> Bool
```

As long as i return simply objects like "test" instead of a MatchCollection i get no error.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Parse and watchkit extension](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30366934/parse-and-watchkit-extension)

Comment: Do you ever read and try [Parse and watch kit extension](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30366934/parse-and-watchkit-extension) and [When to use NSSecureCoding](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17301769/when-to-use-nssecurecoding)

Comment: Generally, you can decode objects that only adhere to `NSCoding` but not `NSSecureCoding` using the technique from this answer: https://stackoverflow.com/a/68522427/10601702. (Doesn't work for this question though, because they don't seem to control **how** their data is decoded)

Answer (score 12):

add in `.h` file

```
 // just the protocol

@interface PacketH: NSObject<NSSecureCoding>
```

add in `.m` file

```
+ (BOOL)supportsSecureCoding {
   return YES;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

If you are using `Swift`, you need to implement `NSSecureCoding` protocol to your class:

```
class Foo: NSObject, NSSecureCoding {
    static var supportsSecureCoding: Bool {
       return true
    }
}
```