# archivedDataWithRootObject: always returns "nil"

Tags: objective-c, nskeyedarchiver

I have a class named `Person` and created a `Person instance` "person".

```
Person *person = [Person personWithName:@"Kyle", andAge:15];
```

Then I tried to encode it using method `archivedDataWithRootObject:requiringSecureCoding:error:`.

```
NSData *personData = [NSKeyedArchiver archivedDataWithRootObject:person 
                                      requiringSecureCoding:YES error:nil];
```

However, the `personData` always returns `nil`. Did I miss something?

**Person.h**

```
@interface Person : NSObject<NSSecureCoding>
@property (strong, nonatomic) NSString *name;
@property (assign, nonatomic) NSInteger age;
+ (instancetype)personWithName:(NSString *)name andAge:(NSInteger)age;
@end
```

**Person.m**

```
@implementation Person
+ (instancetype)personWithName:(NSString *)name andAge:(NSInteger)age{
    Person *p = [Person new];
    p.name = name;
    p.age = age;
    return p;
}
+ (BOOL)supportsSecureCoding {
    return YES;
}
- (id)initWithCoder:(NSCoder *)coder {
    self = [super initWithCoder:coder]; // error: No visible @interface for 'NSObject' declares the selector 'initWithCoder'
    return self;
}
@end
```

---

**Update** (after implementing +supportsSecureCoding in .m):

> Class 'Person' has a superclass that supports secure coding, but
> 'Person' overrides -initWithCoder: and does not override
> +supportsSecureCoding. The class must implement +supportsSecureCoding and return YES to verify that its implementation of -initWithCoder: is
> secure coding compliant.

Comment: And if you use the `error` parameter instead of passing `nil`, does it give more infos on why it failed? Also, do you have error message in console? Is `Person` `NSCoding` (and `NSSecureCoding`) compliant?

Comment: @Larme It told me that "This decoder will only decode classed that adopt NSSecureCoding. Class 'Person' does not adopt it." Then I [implement +supportsSecureCoding in .m](https://stackoverflow.com/a/61102226/8335151),but get another error (have updated in description).

Comment: `NSKeyedArchiver` is linked to `NSCoding`, else, it's doesn't know how to transform that class into `NSData` and reverse. Now, there is the "Secure thing", it's almost the same.  You need to override `supportsSecureCoding` to return `YES` as said in the error message. It's pretty explicit. No? How did you write that? Can you share the code?

Comment: @Larme Have posted the code. TIA:)

Comment: You didn't write `initWithCoder`?

Comment: @Larme If write `initWithCoder`, I get the error `No visible @interface for 'NSObject' declares the selector 'initWithCoder'`.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/230626/discussion-between-larme-and-kyle-wang).

Comment: See https://developer.apple.com/library/archive/documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/Archiving/Articles/codingobjects.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/20000948-BCIHBJDE

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What's wrong: `Person` isn't `NSSecureCoding` compliant. That's the first thing that pops in mind if you ever played with Archiving Custom Class into Data with NSKeyedArchiver (if it's an old developer, he/she would have said `NSCoding`, but that's "almost the same", same logic).
What's the deal with that? It's just how to convert `Person` into `NSData` and reverse. What's the logic? Do you want to save its properties? How? Etc.

**BUT**, your biggest mistake as a developer was to totally ignore the error parameter!

```
NSData *personData = [NSKeyedArchiver archivedDataWithRootObject:person 
                                      requiringSecureCoding:YES error:nil];
```

==>

```
NSError *archiveError
NSData *personData = [NSKeyedArchiver archivedDataWithRootObject:person 
                                      requiringSecureCoding:YES
                                      error:& archiveError];
if (archiveError) {
    NSLog(@"Ooops, got error while archiving: %@", archiveError);
}
```

Then the error would have stated that it was indeed missing the `NSSecureCoding` compliancy

See the documentation of [Archives and Serializations Programming Guide: Encoding and Decoding Objects](https://developer.apple.com/library/archive/documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/Archiving/Articles/codingobjects.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/20000948-BCIHBJDE), you'll see how to implement `initWithCoder:` (from `NSData` to `Person`) and `encodeWithCoder:` (from `Person` to `NSData`).

Applied to your class (and add it to the compliance with: `@interface Person : NSObject< NSSecureCoding >` for instance):

```
- (void) encodeWithCoder:(NSCoder *)encoder { 
    [encoder encodeObject:_name forKey:@"name"]; 
    [encoder encodeInteger:_age forKey:@"age"]; 
} 

- (id)initWithCoder:(NSCoder *)coder { 
    self = [super init]; 
    if (self) { 
        _name = [coder decodeObjectForKey:@"name"]; 
        _age = [coder decodeIntegerForKey:@"age"]; 
    } 
    return self; 
}

+ (BOOL)supportsSecureCoding {
    return YES;
}
```

Note that the strings key (`"name"` & `"age"` needs to be the same for encode/decode, you can use const, etc.)